# Dynamically set Image of a Picturebox in winforms applications?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net

I gets the application.startuppath like below;

> C:\Documents and Settings\aju\my documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\gManager\gManager\bin\Debug

And i have a image here to set for picturebox
 ..\Images\Image1.jpg

what should i do to set the image property of picturebox ?

Answer (score 3):

```
pictureBox1.Load(path_to_picture)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set in design time just browse otherwise use [`PictureBox.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hcd93a3k.aspx).